# Can't make a way to print strings by words/or as 12 characters

Tags: c++, c-strings

To start with, we have array of strings, I have to print this array that way, that one word before space or first 12 characters = one string.

For example, lets say we have string "hello world qwerty------asd" , this must be printed as :

```
hello
world
qwerty------ (12 characters without space)
asd
```

So, it will be easy to do without this 12 characters condition in the task ( just strtok function I guess ), but in this case, I dont know what to do, I have idea, but it works with only 50% of inputs, here it is, it is quite a big and very stupid, I know its about strings functions, but cant make algoritm , thank you:

```
    int counter = 0;// words counter
int k1 = 0;// since I also need to print addresses of letters of third word, I have to know where 3rd word is
int jbegin=0,// beginning and end of 3rd word
    jend=0;
for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
    int lastspace = 0;//last index of new string( space or 12 characters)
    for (int j = 0; j < strlen(*(arr + k)); j++) {
        if (*(*(arr + k) + j) == ' ' ) {  //if space
            printf("\n");
            lastspace = j;
            counter++;
            if ( counter == 3 ) { // its only for addreses, doesnt change anything 
                k1 = k;
                jbegin = j + 1;
                jend = jbegin;
            }
        }
         if (j % 12 == 0  && (j-lastspace>11 || lastspace==0) ) { // if 12 characters without space - make  a new string
            printf(" \n");
            counter++;
            lastspace = j;
        }
        if (counter==3 ) { 
            jend++;
        }
        printf("%c", *(*(arr+k) + j)); // printing by char
    }
    printf("\n ");
}
if ( jend!=0 && jbegin!=0 ) {
    printf("\n Addreses of third word are :\n");
    for (int j = jbegin; j < jend; j++) {
        printf("%p \n", arr + k1 + j);
        printf("%c \n", *(*(arr + k1) + j));
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any reason you do not use any c++? can you use `std::string`?

Comment: "but it works with only 50% of inputs": Can you characterize the 50% that work?  What do they have in common?  When you trace the program with a debugger, at what point does it do something you didn't expect?

Comment: @ScottHunter it doesnt work properly when string is pretty long, and there are more than one 12 characters  without space sequences in the string. And anyway, my code is bullshit, since of size and lack of string functions.

Comment: @user463035818 yep, I am not allowed to , but if u have something for std::string, share please, I can try to remake it for c-string

Comment: why you are not allowed to? they force you to write c in c++ ? :(

Comment: @user463035818 russian education be like )

Comment: Get rid of the for loop.  Use a while loop that just looks for space and prints words.  Once that is working add the condition of also stopping at 12 characters.  It is easier to debug something that partially works.

Comment: @user463035818 if u have some strings function for my task in the mind give me  a chance, I will try to google and use them

Comment: @stark hm, I know it is something with if condition for 12 chars, i just cant imagine another way to make break at 12 characters. And also, I am looking forward to more elegant way with string functions use and more simple code)

Comment: @Tovarisch -- If you were to actually use C++ instead of C, the solution is no more than 10 lines of code, maybe less.  None of this "checking for space" stuff has to be done.

Comment: is there such a big difference between c-string and string? Give me a soluton please for C++, probably I can find there something useful for my task, thank you

Comment: @Tovarisch Is there a big difference? [You be the judge](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/614dc4f18ea58133)

Comment: @Tovarisch A lot of the extraneous code you're doing is checking for spaces.  There is no need for that in C++ if you used things like `istringstream` that automatically detects spaces.  That is a bulk of your code if you look at it carefully.  The code at the link I posted offloads all that work to `operator >>` and `std::istringstream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to understand your code, but to be honest, I have no idea what you are doing there. If you print character by character you only need to add a line break when you encounter a space and you need to keep track of how many characters you already printed on the same line.

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
   char  x[] = "hello world qwerty------asd";
   int chars_on_same_line = 0;
   const int max_chars_on_same_line = 12;
   for (auto& c : x) {
       std::cout << c;
       ++chars_on_same_line;
       if (c == ' ' || chars_on_same_line == max_chars_on_same_line){
           std::cout << "\n";
           chars_on_same_line = 0;
       }
   }
}
```

If for some reason you cannot use `auto` and rage based for loops then you need to get the length of the string and use an index, as in

```
size_t len = std::strlen(x);
for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    c = x[i];
    ...
}
```

Comment: A way much more elegant, thank you lad, but, sorry for my terrible c++ skills, I dont fully understand auto& c and cant edit this code for my array of string ( char **arr) properly

Comment: @Tovarisch i added something without `auto` but, sorry, `char **arr` is beyond what I can handle without getting dizzy. You neeed to store the seperate lines in another array of c-strings?

Comment: @Tovarisch Your original code and question does not show, when, where, or even why you have a `char **arr`.  All you are asking is to parse a string.  What you could do is take the solution given, make it a function, and pass the individual string to the function to parse.

Comment: No, I only must print them, changes in input strings are not neccessary, thank u again, now its up to me to understand  and adapt it. Thank u again, good luck man @user463035818

Comment: There is no need to change input strings.  Do you know what functions are?

Comment: @user463035818 its fk small, elegant and understable, already works with **arr, u r beast man

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thank you man too, need time to increase my knowledge about c++ strings, thank you for the info too

Answer (score 1):

```
printf( "%.12s\n", wordStart);
```

can limit printed chars to 12.

Otherwise there are 2 independent data word starts and line limits.

1. word starts - each transition from white space to word char needs to be tracked.
2. whenever a word is completed = wordchar to whitespace

   - less than or equal to 12 chars since word start. Print whole word + new line.
   - greater than 12 chars. Print 12 chars and dump rest.
3. whitespace followed by whitespace - ignore

Comment: Oh, thank u for the information,  wiil try ur way of solving too, lad